# jQuery use current data after its updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to get the current status of a specified `seat`, so every seat has the status `free` at the beginning, and the status will be changed to `'man', 'women'` or `'child'`.

So after I pick one of this status, for example: `free` to `man`!
And I wanna alert the current status of the seat Ive updated, it shows me the old status `free` and not `man`! Here is the code:

I can't use `click()` function because im adding content than click on `.man, .woman` or `.child`, so i have to use `on()`.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".man, .women, .child", function() {
        var seatNumberHere = $(this).data("seat-number"); //Number of seat
        var seatPerson = $(this).data("person"); //Displays 'men', 'women' or 'child'

        $("[data-the-seat='" + seatNumberHere + "']").attr("data-status", seatPerson); //Updates the attribute data-status="free" to "men"
        alert($("[data-the-seat='" + seatNumberHere + "']").data("status")); //Here is the problem it shows still "free"
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seat" style="top: 10px; left: 130px;"
          data-the-seat="1"
          data-status="free"
          data-toggle="popover"
          data-html="true"
          data-placement="top">
<div class='man' data-person='man' data-seat-number='1'>man</div><div class='women' data-person='women' data-seat-number='1'>women</div><div class='child' data-person='child' data-seat-number='1'>child</div>">
          1
        </div>
```

Comment: could you post the html part

Comment: Of course, I will update it now.

Comment: you add data-content iside this div after ?

Comment: data-content is the popover so yeah its a new html data that will be added, so i used on() to add event for the new html data, but as I said I need the current status of the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the data you get will stuck on the last accessed value because you're changing this last only in DOM

note that

- [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) change this element DOM value 
  and
- [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) will change the element value in a certain memory

so two different things

In order to get same value wether  in dom (attr) or memory
 (data) you should set the value to both of them

See below Snippet :

```js
$(document).on("click", ".man, .women, .child", function() {
    console.log(this);
    var seatNumberHere = $(this).data("seat-number"); //Number of seat
    var seatPerson = $(this).data("person"); //Displays 'men', 'women' or 'child'
    
    
    $("[data-the-seat='" + seatNumberHere + "']").attr("data-status", seatPerson);
    $("[data-the-seat='" + seatNumberHere + "']").data("status", seatPerson);
    //Updates the attribute data-status="free" to "men"
    
    alert("value of attr :"+$("[data-the-seat='" + seatNumberHere + "']").attr("data-status"));
    alert("value of data :"+$("[data-the-seat='" + seatNumberHere + "']").data("status")); //Here is the problem it shows still "free"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="seat"
      style="top: 10px; left: 130px;"
      data-the-seat="1"
      data-status="free"
      data-toggle="popover"
      data-html="true"
      data-placement="top">
      <div class='man' data-person='man' data-seat-number='1'>M</div><div class='women' data-person='women' data-seat-number='1'>W</div><div class='child' data-person='child' data-seat-number='1'>C</div>"
      1
    </div>
```

Comment: Which one is the DOM side, and which is memory side?

Comment: @FlamurBeqiraj , please see above explanation